# EWS SOAP operations - Get Tentative state of a meeting

Tags: soap, exchangewebservices

Using [EWS operations](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi4osTryNbNAhWLB8AKHaS4BrEQFggmMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Foffice%2Fbb409286(v%3Dexchg.150).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFDGtKS6shpjARi1vwAljMu3VQTKQ&sig2=5ZVy_LDPFxzvZkvBXUXwxg) (SOAP) how do I get the **Tentative** status of a meeting?
I can get it using a [GetItem](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi_udeGydbNAhWiKcAKHYDHBuoQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Foffice%2Faa564509(v%3Dexchg.150).aspx&usg=AFQjCNGzo19X-nHjn8X_FL5FPz1HdMy62Q&sig2=p6rPKTaPZNN7QCTgtrAwnA) request setting *AllProperties* instead of *IdOnly* as BaseShape value but I would like to avoid such a big xml response.

Any suggestion?

Request:

```
<m:GetItem Traversal="Shallow">
        <m:ItemShape>
            <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
            <t:AdditionalProperties>
                <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject"/>
                <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:TextBody"/>
            </t:AdditionalProperties>
        </m:ItemShape>
```

Response:

```
<t:IsAllDayEvent>false</t:IsAllDayEvent>
<t:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>Tentative</t:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>
```

( Full request:)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<soap:Header>
    <RequestServerVersion xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" Version="Exchange2013" soap:mustUnderstand="0"/>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <m:GetItem Traversal="Shallow">
        <m:ItemShape>
            <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
            <t:AdditionalProperties>
                <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject"/>
                <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:TextBody"/>
            </t:AdditionalProperties>
        </m:ItemShape>
        <m:ItemIds>
            <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGYxMTJlYTgyLTBmYzEtNGYxZS1iYmViLTI4YmUwNjliN2MzNgBGAAAAAAACkhFyvlR7SJUlGy2d/KnVBwCB2CePXX/CToeJqw2EFOoNAAAAAAENAADu1Rjhkj+hRIRrpcOyI08fAAAXZyRiAAA=" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAADu1Rjhkj+hRIRrpcOyI08fAAAXZ6Nr"/>
        </m:ItemIds>
    </m:GetItem>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it using calendar:LegacyFreeBusyStatus eg

```html
<m:GetItem Traversal="Shallow">
        <m:ItemShape>
            <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
            <t:AdditionalProperties>
                <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject"/>
                <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:TextBody"/>
                <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:LegacyFreeBusyStatus"/>
            </t:AdditionalProperties>
        </m:ItemShape>
```

Comment: Many thanks. Do you have a link to the documentation for that please?

Comment: I think https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa494315(v=exchg.150).aspx would be the closest